# setting this.updateTime but it throws NullPointerException when test is run

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, this

I have this in my test:

```java
final MockKeyReader mockReader = (MockApiKeyReader) getKeyReader();
mockReader.setUpdateTime(100L);
```

`MockKeyReader` has this method:

```java
public void setUpdateTime(final Long updateTime) {
  this.updateTime = updateTime;
  }
```

I thought that because `setUpdateTime` sets the value of `this.updateTime`, when `mockReader.setUpdateTime(100L);` is executed it would be available when the class I'm trying to test looks for it. Am I misunderstanding how `this` works?

This is the line that's throwing the exception:

```java
if (!this.updateTime.equals(ProductionBlocking
          .get(this.keyReader.updateTime(this.config.configId.toString(),
              keyType.PLUSSTAR)))) {
```

I just realised that I'm trying to compare two `Longs` with `.equals()`. I changed the line to:

```java
if (this.updateTime != ProductionBlocking
          .get(this.keyReader.updateTime(this.config.configId.toString(),
              keyType.PLUSSTAR))) {
```

The problem remains though. Both `this.updateTime` and `ProductionBlocking
          .get(this.keyReader.updateTime(this.config.configId.toString(),
              keyType.PLUSSTAR))` are `null`

I expected `mockReader.setUpdateTime(100L);` to set `this.updateTime` in `setUpdateTime` but that hasn't happened.

I've a feeling thin might incorrect understanding on my part.

`ProductionBlocking
          .get(this.keyReader.updateTime(this.config.configId.toString(),
              keyType.PLUSSTAR))` uses interface `ApiKeyReader` and `MockApiKeyReader` is a mock of that.

Comment: this.updateTime should be equal to updateTime and not lastUpdatedTime, or better rename the method parameter to lastUpdatedTime.

Comment: Sorry, that had been changed earlier. Missed the last one. I've fixed that in the query but am still having the issue.

Comment: You are sure that the NPE is inside MockKeyReader thrown? Maybe the method getKeyReader() returns null.

Comment: maybe you could add the line which the NPE is thrown

Comment: The question has been updated with additional info.